# SOLVED - New Edge/Face from Vertices "F" Key not working

Tags: vertices, faces

I'm fairly new to Blender and started retopoing a couple of objects about a month ago.

Everything was going fine until the "F" key decided to stop working. As shown in the pictures below, whenever I want to add a single face, I'll select the middle vert and hit "F," it'll create a triangle instead of a quad. I've tried selecting all three verts, selecting the two edges and hitting "F"... still triangles.

I've also completely uninstalled Blender from my computer and reinstalled, but I'm still having this issue.

Simple Plane Testing..(pics)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Has anyone else run into this problem? Did I accidentally click something to cause this?

I'm using Blender 2.82a

Any help or answers are appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer:
[image]

Thanks you @Electric_Wizard!!!

Comment: Make sure that the **F2** plugin is enabled.

Comment: Oh My Lord!!!! It worked!!! Thank you!! I would have never have figured that out myself lol xD